# will a hashed index on _id be faster than the default b tree index that MongoDB creates?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, objectid, mongodb-indexes

hashed indexes, if evenly distributed, has time complexity of O(1), while b tree index always has complexity of O(log(N)).

So the question is, is the ObjectId that MongoDB creates for the `_id` field be evenly distributed such that the time complexity is indeed O(1)?

Comment: The `_id` is a unique key, so the values cannot be evenly distributed.

Comment: MongoDB stores all indexes in a b-tree, regardless of whether the valued is hashed or not.  Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28330170/mongodb-performance-difference-between-hash-and-ascending-indices-any-reason-no